# Is it possible to add to an existing value in a cell in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which saves monthly values, but also a value for the complete year. Is is possible to add to the yearly value whenever I insert a value for a month?

I want to avoid loading the value first, adding to it in the server-code and writing it again.

Comment: you could use a trigger

Comment: 'course it is , but then worry about corrections (updates , deletes, accidental inserts )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it by adding the values client side, this also saves computing time on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a trigger and insert value in the years table when any value is inserted in the Month table like

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_month ON monthly_table
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
      UPDATE year_table
      SET // insert your values here
      FROM inserted
      WHERE monthly.id = inserted.id;  // something like that, I am not sure about your structure thats why cannot add exact syntax
    END
   GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach to this is avoiding redundant data in your table. When you need year totals, SELECT them.

You didn't tell us your table definition, so I will guess. The table `months` contains

```
 year   int (for example, 2019)
 month  int (1-12)
 value  number
```

You can get the details of this the obvious way: `

```
  SELECT year, month, value FROM months;
```

You can get the details and the yearly sums this way

```
  SELECT year, month, SUM(value) value
    FROM months
   GROUP BY year, month WITH ROLLUP;
```

The result set for this query looks like the other result set, but also contains sums. It looks like this:

```
| year | month | value |
| ---- | ----- | ----- |
| 2018 | 1     | 100   |   detail month values...
| 2018 | 2     | 140   |
| 2018 | 3     | 130   |
| 2018 | 4     | 190   |
| 2018 | 5     | 120   |
| 2018 | 6     | 180   |
| 2018 | 7     | 130   |
| 2018 | 8     | 140   |
| 2018 | 9     | 150   |
| 2018 | 10    | 200   |
| 2018 | 11    | 230   |
| 2018 | 12    | 300   |
| 2018 |       | 2010  | yearly sum for 2018 (month is NULL)
| 2019 | 1     | 100   |
| 2019 | 2     | 130   |
| 2019 | 3     | 160   |
| 2019 | 4     | 140   |
| 2019 | 5     | 190   |
| 2019 | 6     | 240   |
| 2019 |       | 960   | yearly sum for 2019 (month is NULL)
|      |       | 2970  | total sum  (both month and year are NULL)
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q9qg1STdGtLHCnQQxQrpZ7/0)

Why is this a good process?

1. you need to store no extra data.
2. it works correctly even if you update or delete rows in your table.
3. it's fast: SQL is made to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Did something like this, but just totaled the already queried values in javascript client-side.